# Nifi converting Oracle Date to timestamp-millis and adding 00:00:00

Tags: oracle11g, apache-nifi

We have tables in oracle having date field that we are pulling via Nifi with Avro logical types true.

The select * or column name is bringing that record with logical type as timestamp-millis. It may be because oracle stores date with hours, minutes, second. Is there any way to get it in date format in avro logical type?

Comment: how the date is represented right now? please provide an examples in your question what do you have now and what you want (not everybody has an oracle to test).

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Hi Emerald, Yup the reason was same. Even for date field oracle internally stores date with timestamp internally. SO it was coming in that way. We handled the casting in the target Bigquery table.